# How to create and append a log file while creating archive using tar

Tags: linux, bash, unix, logging, scripting

My intention is to create a bash script which will archive the folder every day and create a archive status in a text file.

If I have a folder called /files/daily_updates, I would do something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Create archive of daily update

NOW=$(date +%Y%m%d%H)
LOG_FILE=/var/log/updates_$NOW.log

tar -czvf /archive/daily_backup_$DATE.tar.gz /updates/daily_updates 1> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
tar -ztvf /archive/daily_backup_$DATE.tar.gz 1> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
```

My log file updates_#.log should look like normal log file:

```
10-20-2014 04:45:29 INFO Creating archive of folder..
10-20-2014 04:46:01 INFO Archive created of file: filename, size = 102 MB
10-20-2014 04:48:21 ERROR
```

Few questions:

1. The second tar command overwrites the logs created by the first one, how do I avoid this?
2. I am only able to write standard STDERR and STDOUT of tar so far. Can I put the output in the log file format mentioned above?
3. Is there any alternative, may be a python script or even java?

Comment: I din't understand 2) and 3) but you can solve 1) by changing `>` to `>>` in the second command so you append rather than clobber.

Comment: Re (2)-(3): if you create the tar from `Python,` you could take advantage of the `logging module` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). `tar` would employ https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: thanks >> did the trick. now time for some python.